# reloading jslider after using ajax to change the inputs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jslider

I'm using this jquery jslider pluggin http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/ which works really well. It basically works by 'redrawing' an 'input' item into a slider.

Document ready works fine, and draws the slider as expected, but next I am using an ajax call, based on a user choice, to change the number of 'inputs' on a page and therefore the number of sliders, but what I am having difficulty with is getting the pluggin to 'redraw' the slider over the new inputs after the ajax call.

I tried wrapping the slider calls inside a function initSliders(), see below, so it could be refreshed after the ajax call, but its not redrawing the sliders.

Any suggestions?

plugin required bits:

// before ajax

```
<div id="decide1_right">
    <input id="Sliderx" type="slider" name="area" value="20;100" />
</div>
```

// after ajax

```
<div id="decide1_right">
    <input id="Sliderx" type="slider" name="area" value="20;100" />
    <input id="Slidery" type="slider" name="area" value="20;100" />
</div>
```

// ajax post

```
$.post(
   "<?php echo base_url('index.php/test/getCriteriaItems');?>", 
   {criteria: row_id}, 
   function(data) {
     $("#decide1_grp").html(data);  // returns <input>'s for sliders
   }
);
initSliders();
```

// slider stuff

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initSliders();
});
```

// slider stuff

```
function initSliders() {
   $("#Sliderx").slider({ 
      from: 0, 
      to: 120, 
      step: 0.1, 
      format: { format: '##.0'},
      round:1,
      scale: ['0', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%', '120%'], 
      limits: false,
   });
   $("#Slidery").slider({ 
      from: 0, 
      to: 120, 
      step: 0.1, 
      format: { format: '##.0'},
      round:1,
      scale: ['0', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%', '120%'], 
      limits: false,
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery's ajaxComplete function.. It should fire after every ajax call.

```
$("#Sliderx, #Slidery").ajaxComplete(function () {
   //logic here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/